# Change geoip.location mapping from number to geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using a logstash filter to convert my filebeat IIS logs into location:

```
filter {

    geoip {
            source => "clienthost"
        }
}
```

But the data type in elasticSearch is:

```
geoip.location.lon  = NUMBER
geoip.location.lat  = NUMBER
```

But in order to map points, I need to have

```
geoip.location  = GEO_POINT
```

Is there a way to change the mapping?

I tried posting a changed mapping

```
sudo curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_template/filebeat" -d@/etc/filebeat/geoip-mapping-new.json
```

with a new definition but it's not making a difference:

```
{
  "mappings": {
            "geoip": {
                "properties": {
                    "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            }
    },
     "template": "filebeat-*"
}
```

Edit: I've tried this with both ES/Kiabana/Logstash 5.6.3 and 5.5.0

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but I deleted all the data and reinstalled ES, Kiabana, Logstash and Filebeat 5.5

And now ES recognizes location as a geopoint - I guess previously even though I had changed the data mapping, there was still data that was mapped incorrectly and Kibana was assuming the incorrect data type - probably a reindex of the complete data would have fixed the problem

Comment: If I recall correctly, once it has been created, a mapping can't be changed, you have to delete the index and recreate it with the right mapping.